# One of my large CSS files 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: css, nginx, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, http-status-code-403

I'm using Django with Nginx,in DigitalOcean ubuntu 16.04. All static files are stored in DigitalOcean spaces a product like Amazon S3.

The issue is one of my CSS files bootstrap-xadmin.css got a

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (bootstrap-xadmin.css, line 0)
```

Other of my CSS files are all loaded successfully. The are 2 differences between bootstrap-xadmin.css and other CSS files are:
1.it is larger than other files. It is 456b

2.others are like this

```
  <link href="https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/kjmgstorage/kjmgstorage/xadmin/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css?Expires=1538892849&amp;Signature=kFBt4f7cDsjifd5wQ2xEAxFG6Vs%3D&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=KQBENRUKO4KD6OLDEZSH" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

the **type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"** is behind the **href=''**

But the bootstrap-xadmin.css is like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="site-theme" href="https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/kjmgstorage/kjmgstorage/xadmin/css/themes/bootstrap-xadmin.css?Expires=1537555567&amp;Signature=ujTVQEOBasAkjxX0xVCSqRlcqu4%3D&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=KQBENRUKO4KD6OLDEZSH" />
```

the **rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="site-theme"** is before the **href=''**

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure if this is relevent, but looking at the two links you included they both have `Expires=xxxxxxxx`, one appears to have expired 10 hours ago, and the other 16 hours ago.

Comment: Do the logs tell you anything